# Tasche is used to refer to the bag of a woman, but less often to the bag of a man, is it true?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, meaning-in-context

Once I asked an Austrian female colleague: *Kannst du mir bitte meine Tasche geben?*, pointing to my bag which was laying right next to my colleague. She then replied saying that *Tasche* is rather used to refer to your bag if you are a female, but not when you are a male.

Is this true in the given example? Are there any exceptions? Might this be the case only for certain German dialects?

Comment: The reason why one might think that *Tasche* is used for one used by females rather than males is simply that females are more used to carrying *Taschen* than men.

Comment: I would ask your colleague which word "should" be used referring to a man's bag.

Comment: @Eller My former colleague was suggesting that I should use the specific type of bag I'm referring to, that would be a backpack in this situation, so `Rucksack`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has little to do with the gender of the owner, but bags used by men often have different shapes and therefore different names (like a backpack = Rucksack). But if you see the bag and would usually call it "Tasche", than it irrelevant whose bag it is.
The most frequent use, the one that comes to the mind at first, would be a woman's handbag (Handtasche), an item hardly ever used by men (even though a "Herrentasche" does exist, it has a different shape than a woman's handbag - longer in vertical than in horizontal direction - but serves a similar purpose and would short be called "Tasche", too).
You would also call a larger shopping bag (Einkaufstasche) or travel bag (Reisetasche) this way.

And not to forget that "Tasche" also means "pocket".

Comment: In office-related context *Aktentasche* is also likely.

Comment: Interestingly I hardly ever heard an *Aktentasche* (briefcase) being just called *Tasche* but you are right in that an Aktentasche is another variety of *Tasche*

Comment: That's why I assume, it could be the mismatch causing the original question.

Comment: Re-reading the question and realizing the OP specifically mentioned an *Austrian* colleague, I'm curios whether Hubert Schölnast will post a dissentient answer from a particularly Austrian point of view.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This confirms my intuition that `Tasche`, just like the English `bag`, can be used regardless of the owner's gender. My bag in the given situation was actually a backpack, and my colleague was hinting that I should have said `Rucksack`, as `Tasche` would refer to a woman's bag. Nonetheless, I would also be curios to see if this doesn't have anything to do with a local German dialect.

Comment: Well, in this case... even though technically a *Rucksack* is a *Tasche*, it does not contain the word-part *-tasche*, therefore a German normally would not use the short form *Tasche* for it. Still the gender of the speaker/owner is irrelevant.

Comment: I would call all things "Tasche" which are a bag and have a handle ("Henkel") to carry it main part of the time. Some sort of exception are "Handtaschen" with very long "handles" which in real are shoulder straps. This ones I would call "Tasche" too.

Comment: @Allerleirauh Exceptions into the other direction also exist - my Fahrrad*tasche* (engl. pannier, though this has a broader meaning) has neither handle nor shoulder strap ;-)

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf the "handle" is a rule of thumb for me :-) of course there are more "Taschen" without any handles... But this on Bikes sometimes have handles too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Which noun is used to refer to a thing depends mainly on the thing being referred to and certainly not the speaker's or owner's gender.

*Tasche* is very wide in its meaning; it can be 1) trouser pocket, 2) shopping bag, and 3) basically anything used to carry something. Because of 3), even a *Rucksack* can be called a *Tasche*.

There's lots of compound nouns with *-tasche* which designate specific types of products:

- [Aktentasche](https://www.google.de/search?q=Aktentasche&tbm=isch)
- [Schultertasche](https://www.google.de/search?q=Schultertasche&tbm=isch)
- [Umhängetasche](https://www.google.de/search?q=Umh%C3%A4ngetasche&tbm=isch)
- [Handtasche](https://www.google.de/search?q=Handtasche&tbm=isch)
- [Badetasche](https://www.google.de/search?q=Badetasche&tbm=isch)
- [Bauchtasche](https://www.google.de/search?q=Bauchtasche&tbm=isch)
- [Thermotasche](https://www.google.de/search?q=Thermotasche&tbm=isch) / [Kühltasche](https://www.google.de/search?q=K%C3%BChltasche&tbm=isch)
- [Fahrradtasche](https://www.google.de/search?q=Fahrradtasche&tbm=isch)
- [Babytragetasche](https://www.google.de/search?q=Babytragetasche&tbm=isch)

And, a bit different:

- [Brieftasche](https://www.google.de/search?q=Brieftasche&tbm=isch)

Comment: The question is about the owner's gender, not about the speaker's.

Comment: The owner is the speaker.

Comment: The fact that in this very case the owner and the speaker is the same person is irrelevant. The question is clearly about the owner's gender.

Comment: The idea expressed by OP's colleague is so alien to me that I can't decide. Either way, the answer has been amended. Note that OP wrote *used to refer **if you are a female*** which points to my original interpretation (not the owner of the bag matters, but the one referring to it).

Comment: "_is rather used to refer **to your bag if you are** a female_"

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just like @Eller pointed out, I meant the owner's gender. When writing this question, the English word `purse` also came to my mind, `purse` typically refers to a woman's pouch. That's why I thought that `Tasche` might work in a similar way in German, or in some German dialects.

Comment: @ChrisDev The way your colleague corrected you is just weird. There is no reason to bring gender into it. Why say *Bei einem Mann heißt das nicht Tasche, sondern Rucksack* instead of *Das ist ein Rucksack, keine Tasche*. Even that is somewhat pedantic; I often call my *Rucksack* *Tasche* out of sheer laziness (*Ding* would be even lazier).

Comment: @DavidVogt or maybe that colleague's English wasn't perfect and she just tried to express that when hearing *Tasche* people would rather think of a *Handtasche* than of a *Rucksack*

Comment: @Arsak But that is untrue, *Tasche* can easily refer to a *Rucksack*. *Tasche* is used for a wide variety of things and telling someone not to use that word because they're exclusively thinking of *Handtasche* is bonkers.

Comment: @DavidVogt Yeah, I wonder whether this is different in Austria. Where is Hubert if we need him?! ;)